# How do you solve a question, with no answer?

Tags: riddle

> How do you solve a question, with no answer?
>
> Is it possible?
>
> Well they say everything is possible.
>
> But are they sure; Everything is possible?
>
> Well yes, there is an answer to everything. If there is no answer,
>   then there is no question.
>
> So why did I answer my own question?
>
> Well, there is an answer to that as well.
>
> So what I am asking for is -- What is the answer to my question?
>
> Now this may be tricky.
>
> Especially if you haven't raden my words.
>
> Now can you find the harmony to thy query?

Comment: Is "raden" intentional, or a typo?

Comment: Is the '?' in "Everything is possible?" intentional?

Comment: raden is a hint to what I am hinting at. I used ? In almost every sentence because, well its a question.

Comment: How do you solve a question with no answer?
How do you catch a cloud and pin it down?

Comment: Not a serious attempt at an answer - just be the first to post an answer to any question on any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Looking at the accepted answer, I think you are guilty of "affirming the consequent" here. While it's true that if there is no question then there is no answer, it isn't true that if there is no answer then there is no question. E.g. the question solve x = x + 1 has no answer.

Comment: What is the relevance of "raden"? The accepted answer makes no mention of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is

> How do you solve a question, with no answer?

And, as you say

> If there is no answer, then there is no question.

So, that is the answer!
Such is confirmed when you say

> So why did I answer my own question?

Answer (score 7):

Mu.

That's the solution you'll find in e.g. The Jargon File (there are many versions online, that I'm sure all have this entry) to "unanswerable questions".

An actual possible solution, if this were an extended crossword clue, is

> RHETORICAL

Answer (score 3):

> There is no answer to the question

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: I second [NL628](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43256/nl628)

Comment: @NL628  if there is no answer then you can answer the question

Answer (score 2):

Well, to solve a question with no answer what you need is

> to discover the answer

We all know that

> Everything undiscovered are questions that has no answer.